# How to move a category banner in magento

Tags: magento

I have a question, i hope someone can help me. I would like to move the banner that gets displayed in category page in magento to display on a category page but on the outside (i.e above the category and the left side column). Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for moving category image above the category  you have to make changes in `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/category/view.phtml`

and if you want to move the category image in right  side bar you have to call the category image in the following file

`app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/callouts/right_col.phtml`

Comment: Hi Piyush, How would i go abouts getting the banner moved into 2columns-left.phtml? please advice. Coz when i move the factory code into that phtml file it play havoc on my footer code

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Hi Piyush, The problem i was having seems to have resolved itself. Thanks.